# Custom application class setup for Swagger with a Jersey ResourceConfig

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0

I am following steps as per the Jersey 2.X Project Setup guide(https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-custom-application-subclass). I'm running into a problem with the 'Custom Application' subclass, which provides the sample code below:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet();

        //resources.add(FirstResource.class);
        //resources.add(SecondResource.class);
        //...

        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

        return resources;
    }
}
```

Our project deviates from the example provided above because it extends a Jersey ResourceConfig class, rather than Application class directly. The problem is that the ResourceConfig class itself overrides the getClasses() method and declares it final.

Are you aware of any way to work around this restriction ?

our code :

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class testProj extends ResourceConfig {
    public testProj (){
        property("jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server", "true");

    }
}
```

Please help me providing steps/sample example/ sample code for swagger ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used an extended BeanConfig class in my Jersey ResourceConfig:

```
public class ExtBeanConfig extends BeanConfig {

    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public ExtBeanConfig(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        super();
        if (resources != null) {
            this.resources = resources;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> classes() {
        Set<Class<?>> superClasses = super.classes();
        superClasses.addAll(resources);
        return superClasses;
    }
}
```

That's how I configured it in my ResourceConfig (myClasses is a Set of classes with Swagger annotations):

```
ExtBeanConfig beanConfig = new ExtBeanConfig(myClasses);
beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http, https"});
beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
beanConfig.setScan(true);
```